# Sample size for ANOVA

Tags: anova, sample-size

Is there minimum sample size for each group in 1-way ANOVA? if yes, please give a reference(s), If no, why there is not?

Comment: At least some software will let you run ANOVA with one observation in each group. It's just that the results are not very useful and some results are not defined.

Comment: oneway ANOVA sample size and power calculations are more complex than *t* test calculations. Glanz gives a detailed set of methods for power and sample size calcs on the one-way ANOVA in  Glantz, S. A. (2005). *primer of biostatistics*. McGraw-Hill Medical, New York, NY, 7th edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking, there should be two or more observations in at least one cell (treatment). I.e., if there are n cells, you can perform analysis with (n + 1) observations. Moreover, if you use Poisson regression, it's enough to have just one observation per cell.